# Why can't i use return key word in AngularJS scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, ionic-framework

i am new to AngularJS with Ionic, if i use such a function with a return statement:

```
$scope.searchOnBlog = function(blogURL, text) {
        var searchQuery = blogURL + $rootScope.apiurl + '/posts?filter[s]=' + text;
        searchQuery += '&' + $rootScope.jsonCallback;
        console.log(searchQuery);
        DataLoader.get( searchQuery ).then(function(response) {
            console.log("search response");
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                console.log(response.data.length);
                return response.data;
            }       
        },function(response) {
            console.log( 'search: load error.' );
        });
};
```

and call it from another scope function, like:

```
$scope.entries = $scope.searchOnBlog(blogURL,$scope.searchData.text);
```

I never get any returned object, although i can check there are datas.
Can you please help with this stupid question ?

Comment: Because you can't `return` from an AJAX call. Use a callback or promise.

Comment: Even if this were somehow synchronous, the `return` is in a nested callback function.  The top level function doesn't even attempt to return anything.

Comment: thank you guys, will follow your advice, and sorry for the duplicate